# Meaning of be "Up to plan"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Hi guys I'm creating a wesite and my start name was "Plan Up!" but I found that a company already take that name, so my new thought is "Up2Plan".

I want to know if "Up to plan" means be able to plan, like if your friend wants to hang out and you can say him I'm up to plan. Could I use it for this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, it feels like you depend on a plan or something by those words.

Comment: It does not have the meaning you wish it to have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "naming of new entities" (programming variables, new company / product names, etc.) is outside the remit of this site.

Comment: The main question is to know if "Up to plan" is well use in the contect of having nothing to do and you want to use the app for make something, so is not only about naming the comany. @FumbleFingers

Comment: You've presented no evidence at all to suggest that ***up to plan*** might be an idiomatically established construction in English (it's not). It seems obvious to me that your *only* reason for asking this question is to get help naming your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be `up for {something}` and that means you're amenable.

> Are you **up for** a little tennis?

But if you're feeling tired, or achy, or a little under the weather, you might reply:

> Sorry, I'm not quite **up to it**.

That means you cannot summon the energy or will to do it, or that there is something hindering or preventing you.

So, if you *are* **up to it**, you *can* summon the energy or stamina or will or desire. You're willing and capable.

> We were thinking of taking a 15-mile hike up into the canyon tomorrow. How's you ankle? Has the sprain healed?
>   -- Sure, I'm up to it. I'd like to come along. The ankle's good.

**plan** isn't an activity, but **planning** is, although it doesn't mean that you're willing and able to hang out with someone.

> Your wedding is in six months. Don't you think you should start looking for a venue?  Or do you want to get married on a beach somewhere?
>   --You're right, it's high time I found a place, but I'm just so stressed out with work. I'm not really **up to planning** the whole thing.

Comment: So maybe it's fine to call the app, Up to Plan? That would mean that you dont have any things to do so you use the App to find what to do so you're "Up to Plan" right?

Comment: No, "up to plan" does not mean you don't have anything planned, that  your schedule is open.

Comment: You could ask: *Are you up for just hanging out?*  That means, "Are you amenable to the idea of doing nothing in particular with me?" That is, we will decide what we want to do if an idea comes to us or we think of something interesting or fun to do. We might just end up playing video games or watching a movie or shooting hoops.